# Javascript onclick fails to send value while onfocus of text input

Tags: javascript

If a user clicks the save button as the next action after typing street data the onblur action intercepts the onclick and does not trigger the save. However, if you add some padding (30px) and click above the word save it works but below the word Save it does not work, the same as with no padding. I'm certain users will go right from typing text in the input field then click Save which will fail unless they first click somewhere else and then click Save. I’ve provide html and javascript example below. Is there a way using javascript to solve this issue?

```
<html>
<script>
 function showstreet() { 
   var x = document.getElementById('street').value;
   alert(x);
 }
 function focused() {
   document.getElementById('title').style.display='';
   document.getElementById('street').value='';
 }
 function blured() {
   document.getElementById('title').style.display='none';
   if (document.getElementById('street').value == '') {
       document.getElementById('street').value='street';
   }
 }
</script>
<style>
 .pad5  { padding:5px;  }
 .pad30 { padding:30px; }
</style>
<body>
 <div id="title" class="pad5" style="display:none;">STREET NAME</div>
 <div>
  <input id="street" type="text" name="street" value="street" class="pad5"
   onfocus="focused()" onblur="blured()">
 </div>
 <br>
 <div>
  <input type="button" value="Save" class="pad30" onclick="showstreet()">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I converted this to jsfiddle but I'm not doing something right (newbie) https://jsfiddle.net/eyo63mav/26/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eyo63mav/30/ check this

Comment: Thanks @navnit. Your link reflects what the issue is.

Comment: @navnit your jsfiddle shows the issue but did not solve it. Looks like onMouseDown instead of onClick might be my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onMouseDown` instead of `onClick` in your save button. Then `onMouseDown` will be fired before `onBlur`

Comment: If I focus on the street field and type "123" then click right below the word "Save" it still does the same thing (no alert message). But above the word "Save" and the alert shows "123". I still hope to see a pure javascript solution if possible.

Comment: @Airman, Check the answer. this simple fix is working for me.

Comment: Hey! That seems to be working! I will do some more tests and update shortly. I wonder how the two differ in this issue?

Comment: @Airman, onMouse events called first. onMouseDown, onMouseOut etc. onClick, onBlur etc called after.

Comment: Thanks @TRiNE. A simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

below is working code

```js
function showstreet() {
  var x = document.getElementById('street').value;
  alert(x);
}

function focused() {
  document.getElementById('title').style.display = '';
  document.getElementById('street').value = '';
}

function blured() {
  document.getElementById('title').style.display = 'none';
  if (document.getElementById('street').value == '') {
    document.getElementById('street').value = 'street';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="title" class="pad5" style="display:none;">STREET NAME</div>
<div>
  <input id="street" type="text" value="street" class="pad5" onfocus="focused()" onblur="blured()">
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Save" class="pad30" onclick="showstreet()">
</div>
```

Comment: NOTE: click on Save while onfocus within the street field and "STREET NAME" is displayed.The onclick call to showstreet still fails until your not focused on street.

Comment: try to call onfoucusout javascript function on text box

Answer (score 0):

Styling rarely makes a difference with events -- now, while that's a blanket statement and in lots of cases we find the styling of an inline element such as a link or a paragraph becoming problematic with inline events such as `OnClick` and `OnFocus`, in your case, adding thirty pixels to the size of a button is not your problem.

The problem with your code is that the variable you're assigning your `#title`'s value to is local (it's inside the scope of `showstreet()`, of which can only be accessed by aforementioned function) -- nevermind that, it's never used again. You save a value to it, it alerts the user, and that's it -- it's never reassigned nor reused, so while it'll forever stay as the street name they entered, you'll never see it unless you apply it to something.

It took me a while to figure out what exactly you're trying to save, but I think I've managed it.

Here's the code I've created:

```
var streetValue = "Your street will appear here.";


    function clickedField() {

        // Init title
        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = streetValue;

        // Reset field
        document.getElementById('street').value = '';

    }


    function saveValue() {
        // Reassign streetValue
        streetValue = document.getElementById('street').value;

        // Checking if value was left empty
        if (streetValue === '') {
            document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "Error: No Street Entered!";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = streetValue;
        }
    }
```

(I'm not entirely sure what you had `onblur` for, but it should be very easy to insert back. If you need some help with that, comment on my reply, I'll be happy to.)

Now if we update the HTML with the approprate functions:

```
 <div id="title" class="pad5" style="">STREET NAME</div>
 <div>
  <input id="street" type="text" name="street" value="street" class="pad5"
   onfocus="clickedField()">
 </div>
 <br>
 <div>
  <input type="button" value="Save" class="pad30" onclick="saveValue()">
 </div>
```

Comment: The onblur is used for two reasons. 1: to keep the field title in place if left empty. 2: remove the field title above the input field while the user is on to another field. The idea is to conserve space by placing the title inside the field and only show it above while onfocus to remind the user where they are. However, I do like a lot of what you have here. I was using padding only to help show the issue. Maybe I should have left that out. So far onMouseDown seems to be working in place of onClick.